# pasar variable objeto a formulario Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo he solucionado de esta forma:

Desde la pagina, llamo a la función y asigno el contenido a una variable que depsues asigno a un div.

conv += ''+
                        ''+
                        ''+subDescuento+''+
                '';

Desde la pagina las recojo asi:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    //Lo que sucede cuando abre el modal.

    nameConv = $(e.relatedTarget).data().name; //Aqui tomo la variable nombre de convenio
    desConvenio = $(e.relatedTarget).data().desc; descripcion
    desDescuento = $(e.relatedTarget).data().des_desc; descuento descripcion
 });
```

Comment: ¿Te parece bien si copias tu solución en una respuesta y devuelves a tu pregunta, como estaba originalmente?